# Fedora 18 - HP pavilion g7 - boot after install fails

Tags: linux, boot, installation, fedora

F18 Installation from x64 DVD went fine, then reboot without DVD shows grub, so far so good. But as soon as grub timeout is reached, the screen becomes black and that's it!

No F1, no Ctrl-Alt-F1 works, no nothing, except "power off" button and then F1 which displays only a fiew lines of boot logs (untill udev device search) before showing the shutdown logs and power off.

I could not access logs, but it seems like udev is unable to load devices (graphic card?).

Fedora 16 works perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried some of the usual suspect grub options? Like noacpi, noapic and nomodeset?

Comment: On the grub menu, hit **E** and make sure to remove the `quiet` option (if present) from the kernel line. This should allow you to see some messages that will give you clues. Alse there, try what @terdon suggested.